# Boolean Function In Fortran

Tags: fortran

How do we write boolean functions in Fortran 90. Like if I was making a stack and wanted to make a boolean function isEmpty which would return a true/false.

I tried looking for an example of this but literally couldn't find one. Would someone show me an example of how this could be done.

Comment: LOGICAL FUNCTION FUN1(arg1,...)

Comment: What would the return of the function look like?

Comment: The value of the function name when RETURN is executed is returned
as the function value to the program unit containing the function
reference. `FUN1 = .TRUE.  RETURN

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are three examples of functions returning a logical value, using different syntax. You can choose whether to define a RESULT variable that is different from the function name. I use the first syntax in my code.

```
module foo
implicit none
contains
!
function even(i) result(tf)
integer, intent(in) :: i
logical             :: tf
tf = modulo(i,2) == 0
end function even
!
logical function odd(i) result(tf)
integer, intent(in) :: i
tf = modulo(i,2) == 1
end function odd
!
logical function triplet(i)
integer, intent(in) :: i
triplet = modulo(i,3) == 0
end function triplet
!
end module foo
!
program main
use foo, only: even,odd,triplet
implicit none
print*,even(2),even(3),even(5),even(0) ! output: T F F T
print*,odd(2),odd(3),odd(5),odd(0) ! output: F T T F
print*,triplet(2),triplet(3),triplet(5),triplet(0) ! output: F T F T
end program main
```